# Basex 8.44 db:replace not replacing existing files with the same name

Tags: xquery, basex

The basex [Database_Module db:replace](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#db:replace) "Replaces a resource, specified by $path, in the database $db with the contents of $input, or adds it as a new resource".

[db:add](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#db:add) documentation suggests "A document with the same path may occur more than once in a database. If you want to enforce single instances, use db:replace instead."

Given that I'm not understanding the results I'm getting with the following

I have a collection of xml documents with items such as

```
<item X="14-03-04-SEC_Exempt_Reporting_Adviser_Report_2014-3-4"
         DATE="2014-03-04"
         TYPE="XLSX"
         CRD="170562"
         PRIMARYNAME="LAUNCH ANGELS"
         LEGALNAME=""
         STATE="MA"
         COUNTRY="US"/>
```

I'm using the following xquery to read each file in the collection saving each item with a filename constructed from the item attributes in order to only save items unique to those list of attributes using the db:replace command

```
declare namespace db="http://basex.org/modules/db";
declare namespace file="http://expath.org/ns/file";

for $file in file:list("/mnt/06_08_2016_08_50_20/XML/", false(), "*.xml")
let $doc := doc(concat("/mnt/06_08_2016_08_50_20/XML/", $file))

    for $item in $doc//item
    return
        let $file := replace(concat($item/@CRD,$item/@PRIMARYNAME,$item/@LEGALNAME,$item/@STATE,$item/@COUNTRY,'.xml'),'\s+','')
        return db:replace('FOIA', $file, $item)
```

According to my query

```
let $items := //item[@CRD ='170562']
for $item in $items
return fn:base-uri($item)
```

There are 28 xml files created even though there are only two unique filenames.

```
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
```

I would expect only 2 files to exist in the database with these names not 28 when using db:replace to insert

```
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSNHUS.xml
FOIA/170562LAUNCHANGELSMAUS.xml
```

I do want to enforce single instances, so what am I doing incorrectly.

Thanks Much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the observation, sounds like a bug. Should be fixed soon (see https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1302 for upcoming details).

Once this is fixed, your query will possibly trigger an error (because you are trying to do write to the same location more than once, which is disallowed by all other XQuery Update expressions). Grouping will do the trick:

```
declare namespace db="http://basex.org/modules/db";
declare namespace file="http://expath.org/ns/file";

for $file in file:list("/mnt/06_08_2016_08_50_20/XML/", false(), "*.xml")
let $doc := doc(concat("/mnt/06_08_2016_08_50_20/XML/", $file))
for $item in $doc//item
group by $file := replace(concat($item/(@CRD,@PRIMARYNAME,@LEGALNAME,@STATE,@COUNTRY),'.xml'),'\s+'    ,'')
return db:replace('FOIA', $file, $item[1])
```

Comment: Okay, I'm not clear on why I would need a db:replace function then at all. I did have logic to group by in saxon however the memory consumption was so great I was hoping for a simple alternative like the replace function that just overwrites an existing document.

Comment: I just want to urge you to keep the db:replace functionality as stated in the basex documentation. Such a feature in a database to replace an existing document with one function call using the same filename is a good thing. I believe Marklogic has logic to overwrite an existing document based on the documents associated database filepath.

Comment: The XQuery Update semantics is very strict regarding evaluation of updating expressions and conflicting arising from operations (see e.g. http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#Pending_Update_List). This means that documents will be cached anyway before they are executed, and that we should not allow more than operation with the same target (as it wouldn’t be clear which doc ends up in the db). I assume that the group by solution will even be faster and less memory consuming. db:replace is still required if you have subsequent queries accessing the database, so its semantics won’t change.

Comment: Space in the StackOverflow comments is limited; feel free to send a mail to our mailing list if you have more questions!

Comment: A last note… You can also start your query as follows: for $item in collection("/mnt/06_08_2016_08_50_20/XML/")//item

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following based on feedback from Christian which checks first if the file exists before adding to the database.

```
declare namespace db="http://basex.org/modules/db";
declare namespace file="http://expath.org/ns/file";
declare variable $path as xs:string external;

for $item in collection($path)//item
    group by $filename := replace(concat($item/@CRD,$item/@PRIMARYNAME,$item/@LEGALNAME,$item/@STATE,$item/@COUNTRY,'.xml'),'\s+','')
    return if (not(db:exists('FOIA', $filename))) then
             db:replace('FOIA', $filename, $item[1])        
          else ( )
```